# Dynamic (S)CSS in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sass

I'm trying to allow the user to customize my application using YML files.
When the user updates certain things the CSS needs to be updated as well.

I'd like to solve this problem using dynamic CSS instead. The way I was planning on doing this is to have a settings SCSS file which the other css files import and use.

Here is what I have so far:

**settings.scss.erb:**

```
$width: <%= Rails.application.config.width %>px;
```

**main.css.scss:**

```
//= require settings

@import "settings";

#main {
  width: $width;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Invalid CSS after "$width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "<%= Rails.appli..."`
```

So It seems that the settings are not being passed through the erb parser before being handed off to the SCSS parser, is there any way to solve this.

I'd rather not put everything in `.erb` files since my text editor doesn't support (syntax highlighting and commands) when having scss in erb files

Comment: By user you mean application user (profile) or application deployer who puts it on server?

Comment: Deployer, so once the assets have been generated they will not be generated again (unless you change the settings)

Answer (score 1):

Side stepping the problem where ERB is not being parsed, you are not going to be able to customize the CSS dynamically (I think the main file may require an erb extension). The asset pipeline is designed to serve assets in a way that tells browsers that the are static and are not going to change.

Assuming the erb parsing was working, the width would be rendered during the precompile phase, or on the first request. If you are using Sprockets far-future headers are set to tell the remote clients to cache the content for 1 year. And Sprockets only picks up changes if the timestamp of the file changes, so would never get any new values.

You could force Sprockets to dynamically serve every request, and to not send any headers, but it is not really designed for this and there are significant performance risks in doing so.

Comment: It is not going to be dynamic in the sense that it differs from request to request, just setup to setup. One person might want the thing to be 500px wide, some other might want 1000px, but the assets will need to be regenerated if you update the settings.